# object required error in outlook vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm getting this Object Required error.  See code below.  I don't understand why I'm getting it.  The oitem variable is declared as an Object, and I do a test for the type "MailItem" before attempting to move it.  Please advise.

Alan

```
Public StatsArchiveFolder As Outlook.Folder
'StatsArchiveFolder is set to equal an Outlook.Folder elsewhere
_____________________________________

Sub MoveHarpStatMail()

Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
Dim olappns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oitem As Object
Dim ItemsToProcess As Outlook.Items
Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim sFilter As String
Dim tempMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

On Error GoTo LocalErr

'set outlook objects

Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
Set olappns = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = olappns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'Filter or only MailItems received today
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= " & AddQuotes(Format(Date, "ddddd"))
Set ItemsToProcess = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict(sFilter)

For Each oitem In ItemsToProcess
 If TypeName(oitem) = "MailItem" Then
   Set tempMailItem = oitem
   If CheckSubject(tempMailItem.Subject) Then
     MoveToArchiveFolder (tempMailItem) '<<<Error 424 Object Required ???
   End If
 End If
Next oitem

ExitProc:
Set olapp = Nothing
Set olappns = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set ItemsToProcess = Nothing

...
End Sub

_________________________________

Function CheckSubject(Subject As String) As Boolean

   If (LCase(Trim(Subject)) = LCase(SubjectTitle)) Then
     CheckSubject = True
   Else
     CheckSubject = False
   End If

 End Function

______________________________

Sub MoveToArchiveFolder(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

  If (ArchiveFolder = Nothing) Then
    MsgBox ("The ArchiveFolder object is not set.")
  End If

  Item.Move (StatsArchiveFolder)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the parentheses:

```
MoveToArchiveFolder tempMailItem
```

Basically the parentheses say to evaluate the value of `tempMailItem`. The default property of a `MailItem` is the email's subject, so your code is passing `tempMailItem`'s subject to your function, instead of `MailItem` itself.

Here's an interesting [Daily Dose](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/) post about why. Be sure to read the Rick Rothstein comment.