# Last element of an Outlook email conversation doesn't trigger the Application_ItemLoad event in VBA

Tags: vba, events, outlook

I wrote a Visual Basic macro to mark an opened email as 'unread' again.
For this, I used the event 'Application_ItemLoad' as you see below. However, when testing this for email conversations of Outlook's *group by conversation* function I noticed something weird:

The event won't fire at all when opening the last element of such a conversation group by double clicking it.

Please enlighten me why for every other email this event fires without any problems but only for the last element of a conversation group it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found it.
In my helper module I had this:
`Public EventsDisable, unReadWhenSelected As Boolean`.

From a great [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763955/object-required-error-in-outlook-vba) and Rick Rothstein's contribution on [DailyDoseOfExcel.com](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/) I learned that declaring variables with comma separation leads to the first variable being declared as ***Variant*** instead of the intended *Boolean*.

I just changed to the following and **the error is gone**.

```
Public EventsDisable As Boolean
Public unReadWhenSelected As Boolean
```

I still cannot explain why this weird error happens when EventsDisable is declared as *Variant*. So, if anybody knows, feel free.

```vb
Option Explicit

' When doubleclick opening unread mails, they are automatically marked 'read'. This code will mark them 'unread'.
' Despite that, emails that have been read already and then doubleclick opened will stay 'read'.
' In other words: Doubleclicking a mail won't change its unread property
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.mailItem

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox "Item loaded"
    'If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
            Set myItem = Item
     End If
End Sub

Private Sub myItem_Read()
    unReadWhenSelected = myItem.UnRead
End Sub


Private Sub myItem_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    If Name = "UnRead" Then
        If unReadWhenSelected = True And myItem.UnRead = False Then
            myItem.UnRead = True
            myItem.Save
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```